# Retrieving specific data from column in pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

The data in my pivot table is sorted according to the date (oldest to newest). The column with dates is only comprised of business days. I have formulas to retrieve data from the latest and earliest dates using MAX and MIN functions. Let's say the latest date is 2017-06-30 and the earliest date is 2016-10-01. Then the following functions retrieve the desired data from those dates. (Column A is the date column).

`=GETPIVOTDATA("A";$A$4;"B";"C";"TO_DATE";MAX(A:A);"D";"E")` `=GETPIVOTDATA("A";$A$4;"B";"C";"TO_DATE";MIN(A:A);"D";"E")`

**Note that I have hidden some of the column names.** What I would like to do now is to get data from 5 business days/30 business days/90 business days before the date specified by

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("A";$A$4;"B";"C";"TO_DATE";MAX(A:A);"D";"E").
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without using the WORKDAY function where I have to specifiy the holidays? This was my initial thought, but I don't want to specify the holidays, so the following function won't work

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("A";$A$4;"B";"C";"TO_DATE";WORKDAY(MAX(A:A);-5);"D";"E")
```

I tried to use the OFFSET function, however it seems that I can't use the cell value as a cell reference.

Comment: `it seems that I can't use the cell value as a cell reference` you can, look at `INDIRECT()`

Comment: I see! Will that work even though the value might occur several times?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how I'm supposed to use INDIRECT() so that =GETPIVOTDATA("A";$A$4;"B";"C";"TO_DATE";MAX(A:A);"D";"E") can be used as a cell reference @TimWilkinson